# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I was tring to execute the `BuyCourse.java` file located in the file path `meropadhaiseleniumframework/src/test/java/clinchtech/Tests/BuyCourse.java`. I have my `testng.xml` file in `meropadhaiseleniumframework/src/test/resources/testng.xml`

My `testng.xml` file has code:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<!-- To run the tests parallely, we need to add parallel="tests" thread-count="2", it means 2 <test></test>s are running parallely, which is not suggested in real world systems -->
<suite name="MyTestSuite">
    <parameter name="URL" value="https://demo.meropadhai.com"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name='TestComponents.Listeners'/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="java">
        <classes>
            <!-- Use the fully qualified class name including the package -->
            <class name="Tests.BuyCourse" />
            <!-- <class name="TestNG.Tut1"/> -->
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I tries to execute the code by running `mvn test` from the terminal I got the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project meropadhaiseleniumframework: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/meropadhai6/Documents/GitHub/meropadhai-selenium/meropadhaiseleniumframework/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file /src/test/resources/testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file /src/test/resources/testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:657)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
```

Comment: What command are you running from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed enough, please try below:

Check if you have defined the xml suite file in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version> <!-- Adjust the version as needed -->
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

To run your TestNG tests using Maven, you can use the following Maven command:

```
mvn test
```

This command will trigger the test phase of the Maven build lifecycle, and it will execute your TestNG tests based on your project configuration, including the TestNG suite XML file specified in the pom.xml configuration.

Make sure you are in your project's root directory where the pom.xml file is located before running this command. If your TestNG suite XML file is named testng.xml and is located in the src/test/resources directory, the Maven Surefire Plugin will automatically look for it and execute the tests defined in the XML file.

If you have multiple TestNG suite XML files or want to specify a different suite XML file, you can use the -Dtest option to specify the file as follows:

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/your-testng-suite.xml
```